# Strange behaviour using 3.8.1

Tags: custom-post-types, debug, wordpress-version

I have upgraded some of my blogs into 3.8.1 and I am experiencing a strange behaviour.

I have created in the past two types of themes that use mostly the same mechanism, assigning page templates. The difference between those two types is that in the first I also use the plugin "custom post type template" to assign template into CPT as well, while in the second, I have abolished the CPT for Posts and no template. (Posts in this situation are pure data entries of pictures, text and a couple of custom fields).

The real problem is that when I access my 3.8.x admin from a safari browser (actually any webkit browser), I see old posts (that were trashed) and also page (or CPT) templates are being reset to default randomly. I have switched some in the 3.7.x branch and I don't see that problem. I can't seem to duplicate this problem at will. I don't use any caching plugins (the only plugins I have enabled are the custom post type template, WPML, WPML Media, WPML String translate and WPML translation manager, but I noticed this problem even with WPML disabled)

Do anyone else experience this problem?

Comment: Set debug to true in wp-config.php. It might be that some hook or action or functions got depreciated in 3.8

Comment: It would have been true, I see a no cap deprecation that works either way (with WPML plugins on or off), but the problem is that in Firefox and IE9+ this problem does not happen.

Comment: The PHP, and the WordPress Core, execute on the server before the browser gets involved at all. So you have a problem with Javascript or caching either on the server or in the browser itself. The two notable webkit browser on the market are Safari, which you name, and Chrome. I assume those are the troublesome browsers?

Comment: Yes that is right (about the browsers). My main problem is of the page template nature.